# Find out the largest string from a column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a query in sql for finding the biggest string in a column of row. And I need to get outputted the largest string from the column.

Found smth like this:

- Database is carfind
- Table is carads
- Column is IMAGE1

  ```
  select IMAGE1
  from carads
  where len(IMAGE1) =(select max(len(IMAGE1))from carads)
  ```

But I get error:

`#1305 - FUNCTION carfind.len does not exist`

Comment: post structure of your table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`len` is not a MySQL function. Presumably you mean the length in characters in which case you can use `CHAR_LENGTH`. I.e.

```
SELECT IMAGE1 FROM carads ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(IMAGE1) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Alternatively for length in bytes use `LENGTH`

```
SELECT IMAGE1 FROM carads ORDER BY LENGTH(IMAGE1) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try LENGTH instead of LEN for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL  `LEN()` won't work, it's called `LENGTH()`

```
select IMAGE1
from carads
where LENGTH(IMAGE1) =(select max(LENGTH(IMAGE1))from carads)
```

Using `ORDER` `BY / LIMIT 1` will give only one value , to return all values having length of string equal to maximum length found in table use MAX() as above

Answer (score 1):

There is no function len. There is length function. Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length